# GPT-2 language model: multiplying decoder-transformer output with token embedding or another weight matrix

Tags: python, nlp, pytorch, language-model, huggingface-transformers

I was reading the code of GPT2 language model. The transformation of hidden states to the probability distribution over the vocabulary has done in the following line:

```
lm_logits = self.lm_head(hidden_states)
```

Here,

```
self.lm_head = nn.Linear(config.n_embd, config.vocab_size, bias=False)
```

However, 
In the [original paper](https://www.cs.ubc.ca/~amuham01/LING530/papers/radford2018improving.pdf), they suggested multiplying hidden states with the token embedding matrix whereas [huggingface](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers)  implementation used another matrix.

Is there any advantage of this? Am I missing something?

Comment: Have you raised this issue in the transformer library's github? That might be a better place to ask about this specific design choice.

Answer (score 0):

Both layer sharing the same weights. 
https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/issues/2824